# Grouping all dates as one field and showing the sum of sales

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have converted all dates within my table to reflect as YYYY/MM/01 but I am left with 25 or so of these dates that are all the same and I just want to group them together and I can't figure out how to do it. I'm newish to SQL and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction for this.

Much appreciated!

```
SELECT 
        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ReportedDate), MONTH(ReportedDate), 1) AS Date, SUM(Sales) Sales
FROM 
        dbo.Sales
WHERE 
        YEAR(ReportedDate) = 2018 AND MONTH(ReportedDate) = 01
GROUP BY
        ReportedDate
```

Comment: This code works but shows me 25 or so instances of the date 2018-01-01 and my question is, how do I group these 25 instances into one big group to show the total sales for 2018-01-01.

Comment: Did you try `GROUP BY DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ReportedDate), MONTH(ReportedDate), 1)` ?

Comment: You realize of course that for the code posted, a simple `select sum()` will give you the correct answer.

Comment: The below is another option that works and I think that this is what you might be referring to. I also need to pivot this

`SELECT 
        YEAR(Reporteddate), MONTH(ReportedDate), SUM(Sales) Sales
FROM 
        dbo.Sales
GROUP BY
        YEAR(Reporteddate), MONTH(ReportedDate)
ORDER BY
        YEAR(Reporteddate), MONTH(ReportedDate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are grouping by ReportedDate, for every ReportedDate you will get a record, even though you didn't select ReportedDate in your SELECT clause. Think of it as a hidden column in your data. Instead, try grouping by the functions in your select statement.

```
SELECT 
        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ReportedDate), MONTH(ReportedDate), 1) AS Date, SUM(Sales) Sales
FROM 
        dbo.Sales
WHERE 
        YEAR(ReportedDate) = 2018 AND MONTH(ReportedDate) = 01
GROUP BY
        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ReportedDate), MONTH(ReportedDate), 1)
```

Comment: This is perfect and thank you for explaining. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to your query I suggest you to use [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) function. You would not need to use extra date functions. And I think it's better to show last day of month than first day when showing totals per month

```
SELECT 
    EOMONTH(ReportedDate) AS Date, SUM(Sales) Sales
FROM 
    dbo.Sales
WHERE 
    EOMONTH(ReportedDate) = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)
GROUP BY
    EOMONTH(ReportedDate)
```

Notes:

1. `EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)` gets last day of previous month
2. Use `DATEADD(DD, 1, EOMONTH(ReportedDate, -1))` to get first day of month

Comment: While I agree that showing the end of the month is better, I was asked to convert all dates to reflect the first of the month.

Comment: Have you read notes? I showed how to get first day of month with `eomonth`